Merge rows into 1 cells based on cell value in multiple columns in pandas
I would like to go from:
Name    idtag   Size    frq
Apple   123     Medium  20
Apple   123     Small   10
Apple   123     Small   5
Grapes  875     Small   50
Grapes  875     Small   60
Grapes  875     Medium  80
Mango   8894    Medium  30
Mango   8894     Small   25
Mango   8894     Small   20

to:
Name    idtag   Size    frq
Apple   123     Medium  20
                Small   10
                Small   5
Grapes  875     Small   50
                Small   60
                Medium  80
Mango   8894    Medium  30
                Small   25
                Small   20

I've tried df.set_index(['Name','idtag'])
with this I still get id tags for each row, would like these also to be one cell, like in the Name column

Pandas does not actually provide a cell merging feature, and the result of using set_index(you did in your post) only makes it appear visually as though the cells are merged, but the data itself is not merged. Therefore, it’s not possible to physically merge cells like in Excel using Pandas alone. If you could explain more specifically what functionality you're looking for, I can assist you more accurately.
It's hard to know exactly what you want, but you can convert consecutive data in a particular column to '' to make it look like it's merged. This could be one way to do it.
Code
cols = ['Name', 'idtag']
df[cols] = df[cols].transform(lambda x: x.where(x.ne(x.shift()), ''))

df:
     Name idtag    Size  frq
0   Apple   123  Medium   20
1                 Small   10
2                 Small    5
3  Grapes   875   Small   50
4                 Small   60
5                Medium   80
6   Mango  8894  Medium   30
7                 Small   25
8                 Small   20

If you need the value of the idtag column to appear when the Name column of the df changes, even if the value of the idtag column is continuous, the following code is more appropriate.
cols = ['Name', 'idtag']
cond = df.groupby(cols).cumcount().eq(0)
df[cols] = df[cols].where(cond, '')

same result
Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Grapes', 'Grapes', 'Grapes', 'Mango', 'Mango', 'Mango'], 'idtag': [123, 123, 123, 875, 875, 875, 8894, 8894, 8894], 'Size': ['Medium', 'Small', 'Small', 'Small', 'Small', 'Medium', 'Medium', 'Small', 'Small'], 'frq': [20, 10, 5, 50, 60, 80, 30, 25, 20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

